# How to use visibility.gone() without alliterating relative layout.

Tags: android, layout, view

In my app, based on user interactions, I have images appear, disappear, reappear ect. Based on one interaction, I want a invisible image to NOT reappear again, even if the user does what triggered it's visibility before. I have been using visible and invisible, but when I use the gone method it distorts many things in my layout. (Relative Layout). Is there a better way to go about this? I tried a few other methods suggested by eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: GONE is going to alter a RelativeLayout, all there is to it. GONE acts as though the view isn't even included, it contains no space within the layout. In a RelativeLayout that is going to alter the way the rest of the view parameters are measured. VISIBLE and INVISIBLE should work, what exactly does it distort?

Comment: Didn't know I could change ImageView's image resource on the fly, that solved it quick.

Comment: If you want to hide the view and still have it used for layout, use INVISIBLE. If you want to remove it entirely (GONE or ViewGroup.removeView()) and not affect the layout, you need to rethink your layout.